# Why must we clean up the stack

Tags: assembly, stack

Im taking an assembly class and we're currently learning about the stack. From what I've learned everything that's pushed into the stack must eventually be popped (cleaning up the stack). Why do we absolutely need to clean up the stack? I've read it is to prevent memory leaks, is that it?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

There is only a certain amount of stack for a given thread of execution.

Its purpose is to temporarily hold data needed when a function is called (such as the return address and parameters passed to the function).

If you do *not* clean up the stack when your function exits, you will eventually run out of stack space.

Also, as a general rule that goes beyond just the stack, any resource your program uses (stack space, heap space, file handle, etc.) should be held for the shortest possible amount of time to improve overall efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The stack is a finite amount of memory, and as with any memory allocation system if you never clean it, it'll simply grow and grow. Eventually you'll overflow the stack and all hell breaks loose as you overwrite other areas of memory or simply generate an invalid address.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't clean up the stack, how will the calling function find its variables?  The callee will run, do some operations with its own variables on the stack, and then return to the caller - now what can the caller do if the stack pointer has changed?  How can it restore it to figure out where its own stack variables are?  The only answer is to clean up the stack - it doesn't matter who does it (callee or caller), but *someone* has to.

The term "memory leak" usually refers to losing the pointer to a dynamic memory allocation so that you can't `free()` that allocation.

Comment: "memory leak" usually refers to losing the pointer because the stack is in fact always cleaned up (compiler enforced).  If it were still up to the user to clean up the stack (as it is with assembly), one could in fact also leak stack memory and we would in fact talk of "stack memory leaks" and "heap memory leaks".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers most processors I've used put the return address from a function call on the stack.

The RET/RTS ( or whatever return syntax if used for your processor ) simply pulls the return address from the stack and sets the PC, ProgramCounter, to that address.

If the function puts  additional variables on the stack but does not remove them then the RET will pull back the wrong value and will return to an incorrect address causing all sorts of odd behaviour and or exceptions/traps.

Faults caused by this sort of behaviour can become very difficult to debug especially if they do not fault immediatley

Answer (score 2):

Each function might use the stack, even if some dont you will get nesting of function calls in your programs  one() calls two() two calls three(), etc.

So if function one has local variables A, B, C on the stack, then it calls two, two has two variables it is using E and F on the stack.  Then three has G and H on the stack.  If you do not restore the stack pointer to where it was when three entered, when you return to two, it will think it is accessing E and F but will instead be accessing G and H or something else depending on the stack frame for the three() function.

You dont get a memory leak you get crash.  Sometimes you get lucky and survive, that could be the nature of the code for those functions, but in general it will cause your compiled code for higher level functions that called you to fail.

Now it is memory leak *like* in the sense that one function is trashing someone elses ram, sure.

In the case of processors that use the stack for return values, that just makes it worse, the crash or strange behavior is more guaranteed and worse.

Answer (score 1):

Software routines (functions) can share the stack to get the calling parameters and to return variables as well as remembering the return address of the caller.

As the stack pointer in assembly is typically a register, it's a kind of global variable. If at the end of a function, the stack pointer is not set to the proper location ("stack cleanup"), lots of bad things can happen. The system can return to the wrong address, the caller could pop the wrong return value, there can be stack overflow, underflow, etc.

Comment: @artjomb. I'm having trouble finding what is not so stellar in that link after having done 20 change requests. I got a few obvious rejects but some were tests. Is your meta message accurate?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the links. I learned that code changes are not allowed (makes sense) and that grammar improvements are subjective! Happy Easter.

Comment: What's wrong with keeping a record of this discussion?

Comment: Since I deleted my comments already, this is only half a discussion, therefore not very useful *and* has nothing to do with this post. Nobody besides diamond moderators can see deleted comments.