# x86 cdecl calling convention, why bother cleaning the stack?

Tags: assembly, memory-management, x86, cdecl

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) wikipedia page shows an example assembly code of a caller-clean up convention, where the caller cleans the arguments from the stack.

*Note: I've removed the provided comments and added my own*

```
int callee(int, int, int);

int caller(void)
{
    return callee(1, 2, 3) + 5;
}
```

```
caller:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp

    push    3
    push    2
    push    1
    call    callee
    ; at this point we returned from callee() and our result is saved in eax

    add     esp, 12    ; now we clear the stack by adding 12 (space occupied by 3 ints) to esp
    add     eax, 5
    mov     esp, ebp   ; and here we move the value of ebp to esp, so that "esp = ebp"
                       ; meaning that we could've substracted a million bytes from esp
                       ; instead of just 12 and it wouldn't have made a difference, as we
                       ; are literally assigning a new value to esp here
    pop     ebp
    ret
```

A similar question was already asked ([Why must we clean up the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832312/why-must-we-clean-up-the-stack)) and all the answers say pretty much the same thing: the stack isn't infinite so we must clean it up, but in this case it's not like we are wasting stack memory, the memory occupied by those 3 pushes gets "freed" when we reset the stack frame, making it avaible for later use.

Comment: It's true that in this case it doesn't matter as you only call `callee` once, but what if it was in a loop running thousands of iterations?

Comment: Yes, that code-gen is silly, the `add esp` should be optimized away like real compilers do: look at the `gcc -m32 -O2 -fno-omit-frame-pointer` pane in https://godbolt.org/z/4bdnWjz3Y for a version that wastes instructions messing around with EBP like this, but at least has the benefit of avoiding the `add`.  vs. a version that just does `add esp` / `ret`.  (The extra 16 bytes it allocates before the push/calls is a GCC bug, [Why does GCC allocate more space than necessary on the stack, beyond what's needed for alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63009070))

Comment: For a loop, you could allocate the space once ahead of the loop, and use `mov` instead of `push` to store new args inside the loop.  (See the Godbolt link for the GCC `-maccumulate-outgoing-args` version; that's what that option does.  See also [Why does gcc use movl instead of push to pass function args?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4534791) - that used to be the default because `push` was slower on old CPUs.)

Comment: So really the problem with this example is the pointless instructions that do stuff with EBP.  Remove those and the example makes sense.  Which is what real compilers do with optimization enabled.

Comment: Related, not quite a duplicate: [Stack must be clean before function epilogue confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29185343)  -  the `push ecx` is being used as an optimization for `sub esp, 4`